# Calling native functions which want a pointer to a pointer from F#

Tags: .net, f#

I want to use the Direct3D 11 API (d3d11.dll) from F#. Now that [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX) is archived, [Silk.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET) seemed a reasonable alternative for .NET bindings. I have a working example in C#, but I don't know how that translates to F#. (As may soon be apparent, calling native code is very new to me.)

Here's the API bindings:

```cs
// There's overloads which accept both pointer and byref arguments, including all the permutations.
// https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET/blob/b343d1a65c70b493d719fca611df3a5a1f867792/src/Microsoft/Silk.NET.Direct3D11/D3D11.gen.cs

public unsafe partial int CreateDevice(IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter, D3DDriverType DriverType, nint Software, uint Flags, D3DFeatureLevel* pFeatureLevels, uint FeatureLevels, uint SDKVersion, ID3D11Device** ppDevice, D3DFeatureLevel* pFeatureLevel, ID3D11DeviceContext** ppImmediateContext);

// ... etc.

public unsafe partial int CreateDevice(ref IDXGIAdapter pAdapter, D3DDriverType DriverType, nint Software, uint Flags, in D3DFeatureLevel pFeatureLevels, uint FeatureLevels, uint SDKVersion, ref ID3D11Device* ppDevice, ref D3DFeatureLevel pFeatureLevel, ref ID3D11DeviceContext* ppImmediateContext);
```

Here's how I can call it from C#:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Silk.NET.Core.Native;
using Silk.NET.DXGI;
using SD3D = Silk.NET.Direct3D11;
using WD3D = Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11;

public static unsafe class Interop
{
    [LibraryImport(
    "d3d11.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice", SetLastError = true)]
    [UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    private static partial int CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(nint dxgiDevice, out nint graphicsDevice);

    public static WD3D.IDirect3DDevice CreateDevice()
    {
        using var d3d = SD3D.D3D11.GetApi();

        SD3D.ID3D11Device* pSD3DDevice;

        SilkMarshal.ThrowHResult(d3d.CreateDevice(
            pAdapter: null,
            DriverType: D3DDriverType.Hardware,
            Software: 0,
            Flags: (uint)SD3D.CreateDeviceFlag.BgraSupport,
            pFeatureLevels: null,
            FeatureLevels: 0,
            SDKVersion: 7,
            ppDevice: &pSD3DDevice,
            pFeatureLevel: null,
            ppImmediateContext: null
        ));

        using var pSDXGIDevice = pSD3DDevice->QueryInterface<IDXGIDevice3>();

        SilkMarshal.ThrowHResult(CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice((nint)pSDXGIDevice.Handle, out var pUnknown));

        var device = WinRT.MarshalInterface<WD3D.IDirect3DDevice>.FromAbi(pUnknown);
        Marshal.Release(pUnknown); // idk if needed anymore

        return device;
    }
}
```

Here's what I have in F#:

```ml
module Interop =
  open System.Runtime.InteropServices

  // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.interop/nf-windows-graphics-directx-direct3d11-interop-createdirect3d11devicefromdxgidevice
  [<DllImport(
    "d3d11.dll",
    EntryPoint = "CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice",
    SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall
    )>]
  extern int32 CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(nativeint dxgiDevice, nativeint& graphicsDevice)

  open Silk.NET
  open Silk.NET.Core
  open Silk.NET.Core.Native

  let createDevice () =
      use d3d = Direct3D11.D3D11.GetApi ()

      let mutable pSD3DDevice : Direct3D11.ID3D11Device nativeptr = NativePtr.nullPtr

      SilkMarshal.ThrowHResult(d3d.CreateDevice(
        NativePtr.nullPtr, (* pAdapter *) 
        Native.D3DDriverType.Hardware, (* DriverType *) 
        System.IntPtr.Zero, (* Software *) 
        uint32 Direct3D11.CreateDeviceFlag.BgraSupport, (* Flags *) 
        NativePtr.nullPtr, (* pFeatureLevels *) 
        0u, (* FeatureLevels *) 
        uint32 Direct3D11.D3D11.SdkVersion, (* SDKVersion *) 
        &pSD3DDevice, (* ppDevice *) 
        NativePtr.nullPtr, (* pFeatureLevel *) 
        NativePtr.nullPtr (* ppImmediateContext *) 
      ))

      let d = NativePtr.toByRef pSD3DDevice
      use pSDXGIDevice = d.QueryInterface<DXGI.IDXGIDevice3> ()

      let mutable pUnknown = System.IntPtr.Zero
      SilkMarshal.ThrowHResult(CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice (NativePtr.toNativeInt pSDXGIDevice.Handle, &pUnknown))
          
      let device = WinRT.MarshalInterface<Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.IDirect3DDevice>.FromAbi(pUnknown)
      ignore <| Marshal.Release pUnknown

      device
```

Both implementations work, though I have no idea if either implementation is 'correct'.

**My specific question**

In my F# implementation, I'm using the overload where `ppDevice : ID3DDevice nativeptr byref`, whereas my C# implementation is using the overload where `ppDevice : ID3DDevice nativeptr nativeptr`. How do I use the latter overload from F#?

If I change my F# to:

```ml
let mutable pSD3DDevice : Direct3D11.ID3D11Device nativeptr nativeptr = NativePtr.nullPtr
// ...
let d = NativePtr.read (NativePtr.read pSD3DDevice)
```

I get a null reference exception on that last line.

If I understand correctly, my C# implementation declares a nativeptr, `SD3D.ID3D11Device* pSD3DDevice`, which will be initialized with the default value (nullptr?) and then when it calls CreateDevice, it uses `&` to obtain a pointer to that pointer.

So, maybe the equivalent in F# would be something like:

```
let pSD3DDevice : Direct3D11.ID3D11Device nativeptr = NativePtr.nullPtr
let ppSD3DDevice : Direct3D11.ID3D11Device nativeptr nativeptr = // some fn to obtain the address of pSD3DDevice?
```

But that's starting to get real messy!

**My broad question**

What's the more idiomatic F# way of calling this method(s)?

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712074341/https://pblasucci.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/managing-pointers-or-fs-platform-invoke-gotcha/) led me to thinking I should be using the all byref overload, however CreateDevice requires a lot of nulls so the right overload can't be picked when I try to call it like:

```ml
SilkMarshal.ThrowHResult(d3d.CreateDevice(
  null, (* pAdapter *) 
  Native.D3DDriverType.Hardware, (* DriverType *) 
  System.IntPtr.Zero, (* Software *) 
  uint32 Direct3D11.CreateDeviceFlag.BgraSupport, (* Flags *) 
  null, (* pFeatureLevels *) 
  0u, (* FeatureLevels *) 
  uint32 Direct3D11.D3D11.SdkVersion, (* SDKVersion *) 
  &pSD3DDevice, (* ppDevice *) 
  null, (* pFeatureLevel *) 
  null (* ppImmediateContext *) 
))
```

And trying to call it like this:

```ml
SilkMarshal.ThrowHResult(d3d.CreateDevice(
  Unchecked.defaultof<DXGI.IDXGIAdapter byref>, (* pAdapter *) 
  Native.D3DDriverType.Hardware, (* DriverType *) 
  System.IntPtr.Zero, (* Software *) 
  uint32 Direct3D11.CreateDeviceFlag.BgraSupport, (* Flags *) 
  Unchecked.defaultof<_ byref>, (* pFeatureLevels *) 
  0u, (* FeatureLevels *) 
  uint32 Direct3D11.D3D11.SdkVersion, (* SDKVersion *) 
  &pSD3DDevice, (* ppDevice *) 
  Unchecked.defaultof<_ byref>, (* pFeatureLevel *) 
  Unchecked.defaultof<_ byref> (* ppImmediateContext *) 
))
```

leads to:

> FS0412    A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.